# Django Many to many field using a unique key instead of the primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I've got a django model that has a self, asymmetrical many to many relationship.
I would like that relationship to reference objects using a unique identifying field other than the table's primary key field.

I could not find any documentation about specifying a field to the ManyToMany object's foreign key used to identify the related objects. Is there a way to do that?

Here's an example:

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
      uuid = models.UUIDField(null=True, unique=True, editable=False)
      data = models.TextField()
      dependencies = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False,
                                            related_name="dependents")
```

In the example above, dependencies will be a mapping of `IntegerField`s to `IntegerField`s because that's the field type of the `id` primary key implicitly created in `Annotation`.

Instead, I wish the relationship table (used to maintain the relationship) will use the `uuid` field I manually defined (instead of the `id` field).

Ideally I would assume replacing `self` (first parameter to `ManyToManyField`) with `self.uuid` or `Annotation.uuid` will do just that, but unfortunately this errors with the following:

```
ValueError: Related model 'Annotation.uuid' cannot be resolved
```

Comment: you can assign a `primary_key = True` to the field you would like to reference

Comment: What about adding `unique=True` ?

Comment: It might help you to define a through table to understand what is going on behind the scenes (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @chaggy I'd like one field to be the primary and another to be the one used for the manytomany. Jerin I did. this does not help control which field is used by manytomany. gersbrett I have. answer still eludes me.